# What is the problem of markers2.asy for TeXHead?

Tags: asymptote

```
size(10cm,0);
import markers;
import geometry;
import math;

pair A=0, B=(1,0), C=(0.7,1), D=(-0.5,0), F=rotate(-90)*(C-B)/2+B;

draw(A--B);
draw(A--C);
pen p=linewidth(1mm);
draw(B--C,p);
draw(A--D);
draw(B--F,p);
label("$A$",A,SW);
label("$B$",B,S);
label("$C$",C,N);
dot(Label("$D$",D,S));
dot(Label("$F$",F,N+NW));

markangle(A,C,B);

markangle(scale(1.5)*"$\theta$",radius=40,C,B,A,ArcArrow(TeXHead),1mm+red); // <<---
markangle(scale(1.5)*"$-\theta$",radius=-70,A,B,C,ArcArrow(TeXHead),green); // <<---

markangle(Label("$\gamma$",Relative(0.25)),n=2,radius=-30,A,C,B,p=0.7blue+2);

markangle(n=3,B,A,C,marker(markinterval(stickframe(n=2),true)));

pen RedPen=0.7red+1bp;
markangle(C,A,D,RedPen,marker(markinterval(2,stickframe(3,4mm,RedPen),true)));
drawline(A,A+dir(A--D,A--C),dotted);

perpendicular(B,NE,F-B,size=10mm,1mm+red,
              TrueMargin(linewidth(p)/2,linewidth(p)/2),Fill(yellow));
```

From https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/markers2.asy , I change

```
markangle(scale(1.5)*"$\theta$",radius=40,C,B,A,ArcArrow(2mm),1mm+red);
```

to

```
markangle(scale(1.5)*"$\theta$",radius=40,C,B,A,ArcArrow(TeXHead),1mm+red); // <<---
```

and the output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a margin problem with TeXHead. I examined the files `markers.asy` and `plain_arrows.asy` but not easy to understand.
Moreover a simple `draw(path p,ArcArrow(TeXHead))` gives a correct picture.

I think you can report an issue.
I propose here a workaround by playing with `PenMargin(-0.5,0.5)`, it seems to be ok for TeXHead for different sizes but I cannot guarantee any strange behavior.

```
size(10cm,0);
import markers;
import geometry;
import math;

pair A=0, B=(1,0), C=(0.7,1);

draw(A--B);
draw(A--C);
pen p=linewidth(1mm);
draw(B--C,p);
label("$A$",A,SW);
label("$B$",B,S);
label("$C$",C,N);


markangle(A,C,B);

markangle(scale(1.5)*"$\theta$",radius=40,C,B,A,ArcArrow(TeXHead),1mm+red,PenMargin(-.5,-0.5)); 
markangle(scale(1.5)*"$-\theta$",radius=-70,A,B,C,ArcArrow(TeXHead),green,PenMargin(-.5,-0.5));
```

[image]